# What circumstances would encourage polyandry across a species as the most likely outcome?

Tags: biology, environment

In this world, the nuclear family took a different route. The wife of a household would marry multiple husbands. This would usually be two, although wealthier wives might have more if they can support them. These husbands would usually be related (brothers, cousins, etc), but having no blood ties with the woman.

In our world, this is unlikely to happen. Males are unlikely to tolerate such a situation, and fight each other for dominance. In this case, I want the multiple-husband to one wife setup to actually favor cooperation over competition when it comes to who gets to reproduce. After thousands of years natural selection would favor males who can share a mate instead of fighting over one. This would eventually lead to a much less confrontational species.

I want this to be the common situation across the human species. What set of factors (biological, environmental) would allow me to make this possible in the human race?

Comment: You could make males carry the baby. That way each male can have their own child to ensure their lines continuity and they won't all need to wait a year before the other males have a chance of being satisfied.

Comment: Have fewer females than males.  See for instance China's one child per family policy, or its history: https://qz.com/519572/it-was-normal-for-women-in-18th-and-19th-century-china-to-have-two-husbands/

Comment: Heinlein's *The Moon is A Harsh Mistress* had such a society on the Moon, claiming it started from a lack of females.

Comment: How far from the human genotype are you willing to stray? Would you allow exotic approaches that entail significant alterations in human biology, or do you want a more sociocultural approach in which more or less 'typical' humans would opt for polyandry?

Comment: Having less women than men does not mean polyandry would take place. Hell, even with about 50/50 rate, you still gets polygamy in some places, which means there are celibate men in those societies. What would those women provide to their husbands that invert the classical dynamic ? What trait would the husband have that foster this attitude ?

Comment: Polygamy among a species where the sex-at-birth ratio is nearly 50/50 is always problematic at best. It's even worse when it's polyandry, because the limit on human reproduction is the female... and you're talking about many women going without husbands at all, while those with extra husbands can't get extra pregnant. Inverting social elements is a low form of storytelling, nd it's well past the era where this was edgy.

Comment: This looks like your other question [How do I limit resources to make polyandry the most effective survival option?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/169961/how-do-i-limit-resources-to-make-polyandry-the-most-effective-survival-option)

Comment: @MakorDal: Quite obviously, the women provide sex, the men provide increased economic benefits.  Taken to an extreme, consider prostitution, where one woman benefits economically from having sex with many men.

Comment: @jamesqf Safest bet would be to make men completely addicted to sex - with women only, then ?

Comment: This experiment has been done many times in different parts of the World. The main thing is for the woman to have the higher status. Then she can have multiple husbands... what happens to the other women? They have boyfriends, but not husbands (not their own husbands anyway) and being lower status their offspring are likely the same.. Western concept of marriage isn't the only one.

Comment: @MakorDal: Why would you need men to be addicted to sex?  (Even assuming that's actually possible.)

Answer (score 4):

A simple change that might help (but in no way guarantees) the creation of such a situation might be:

*Reproductive control*

Give women the ability to consciously abort pregnancies, in much the same way that rabbits (when under stress) will self-terminate a pregnancy. This then passes an *awful* lot of control and power to the women, who are now the gatekeepers of whether any given Male gets to reproduce. This small change then logically leads to more matriarchal societies, and possibly even a straight inversion of the Male/female power dynamic.

Something else that may (or may not depending on the course of history and culture in your world) help with this is that *childbirth is hard*. The way we’ve evolved has left us with a singularly dangerous (for the mother)  Reproductive method. Especially pre-modern-medicine childbirth was really quite likely to flat out kill the mother (leading to a skewed Male/female ratio). Couple that with women holding the reproductive choice and they have every reason to assemble ‘harems’ of men from which to choose the ideal one to risk having a child with (which also bolsters your evolutionary goal of making co-operative men the norm, since uncooperative men are unlikely to be seen as the ideal choice).

For those women where childbirth is easy (Some Victorian families got *large*) having many fathers not only makes all the fathers act for the benefit of all children but it’s also the genetic equivalent of spread-betting (no pun intended). If any one father has a critical defect it’s less likely to affect your bloodline later on.

When modern medicine rocks up there’s no reason to change the established dynamics, so polyandry remains the norm but there are also lots of single ladies.

Guess someone shoulda put a ring on it.

Comment: When you speak about skewed male to female ratio, you don't seem to take into account the fact that most work or war related death were men. Worse : at some point in history, only female life expectancy was recorded because it was too wonky for male.

Comment: Women always had solutions to stop childbearing. But their partner could sometime punish them for... well abortion, of course, but also for miscarriage - however unfair that is. So self abortion, even if disguised, seems dangerous.

Comment: @MakorDal: Yeah. Not really. This would be a change pretty far back in evolutionary history, so it’s pre ‘if I chew this particular herb there’s a chance I might miscarry’ levels of intelligence, and if it’s anything like the rabbit’s self-termination the foetus just gets reabsorbed. No evidence. Nothing.

Comment: You’re right about population skew. I was approaching the problem purely in isolation.

Comment: The self-termination of pregnancies already exists in harsh times : women are far more prone to miscarriage. The way you present this, this function is voluntary, no ? The problem I see is that women who don't give child to the tribe (before refusing to giving it to their husband) might have some social problem, not only with men but also with other women "who did their part". Human don't have the birth rate of rabbits that allow for this mechanic, I fear. But, it might lead to sedentary women female tribes and nomad male tribes that barter children. Then evolve from her, maybe.

Comment: @MakorDal: it’s just as likely that men who try to force women to give birth to their child will be shunned by the community and end up with no children at all. Possibly moreso.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve heard that lots of Native American cultures, such as the Hopi and Iroquois were matriarchal societies, where most things were inherited through the female line, and women were in charge. Your civilization could be descended from a culture similar to them.

Comment: Please add some evidence to this, an "I've heard..." answer is not an answer. I would love to +1 your answer because it takes a cultural approach rather than reproductive or a physiological, but until it's more developed it doesn't really deserve it. There are to this day cultures that do practice polyandry and it has to do with the belief that the child inherits from all parents. Even if it's not true, so long as people believe it they will partake in this practice.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriarchy
Here

Answer (score 1):

A necessary aspect is that the male/female proportion would need to be unbalanced. 1 woman is born for every 3 men born, for example.

Assuming that we're talking about a human-like species, the problem is that society might evolve in such a way that women get even more focused on a child-bearing role, because now there's fewer women going around (a stable population would have to have each woman having 4 children). There would be no way to get around the need for these women to spend most their lives having children. To achieve what you're looking for, child-bearing would also have to be biologically easier, safer and faster.

I would also have women be significantly bigger and stronger than men on average so that it would be difficult for a man to "monopolize" a woman.

Answer (score 0):

Polygamy, even where is allowed, tend to be rare and only a privilege to few ones. Discrepancies in the male/female rate can be ignored.

Women leading the society, with more representativity and importance to this society are important factors. Men losing status too (Nothing new here).

A age gap among wife and her husbands, as well social differences with those husbands looking the marriage as social ascention chance would work well. To those women, show multiple husbands would be a status signal, as well men with multiple wives shows right now.

Cultural elements that brings more power and relevance to women than to the men could swap patriarchal old ones, like, for instance, patriarchal religions for matriarchal religions (or, at least, bring more importance to matriarchal elements in the same religions), the answer of @Daikyu Maryu lights well it.